# how to Draw the letter geometrically by points

Tags: graphics

I have the given letter below. I want to draw it geometrically by using trigonometry and other formulas.Help me draw the letter OR give me the idea to draw the letter of any language using formulas. Just like O,P,G..etc.,.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this related to *Mathematica* ? Or are you asking just for thecmathematics behind it ?

Comment: Figure out a way to find the shape on the critical strip of the  Riemann zeta, encode that, done. Win Fields medal along the way. Otherwise, look into perhaps getting some trig series based on Fourier machinations on the shape. Else, segment it and use compositions of splines/beziers...

Comment: Ya thank  for your reply. Please give me the basic commands or basic code for any letter in mathematica

Comment: `FromCharacterCode@2949` - *Very* fast, no math!

Comment: I wonder ... No, I better don't

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the code here:

[Making Formulas… for Everything—From Pi to the Pink Panther to Sir Isaac Newton](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/05/17/making-formulas-for-everything-from-pi-to-the-pink-panther-to-sir-isaac-newton/)

See the function, `pointsListToLines`, a third of the way down the page.

Here is a copy of the code from the CDF:

```
pointListToLines[pointList_, neighborhoodSize_: 6] := 
 Module[{L = DeleteDuplicates[pointList], NF, \[Lambda], lineBag, 
   counter, seenQ, sLB, nearest,  
               nearest1, nextPoint, 
   couldReverseQ,  \[ScriptD], \[ScriptN], \[ScriptS]},
  NF = Nearest[L] ;
       \[Lambda] = Length[L];
  Monitor[
   (* list of segments *)
   lineBag = {};
   counter = 0; 
   While[counter < \[Lambda],
    (* new segment *)

    sLB = {RandomChoice[DeleteCases[L, _?seenQ]]}; 
    seenQ[sLB[[1]]] = True;
    counter++;
    couldReverseQ = True;
    (* complete segment *)

    While[(nearest = NF[Last[sLB], {Infinity, neighborhoodSize}];

      nearest1 = 
       SortBy[DeleteCases[nearest, _?seenQ], 
        1. EuclideanDistance[Last[sLB], #] &];
                 nearest1 =!= {} || couldReverseQ),
                  If[nearest1 === {},
                   (* extend the other end; 
      penalize sharp edges *)
                   sLB = Reverse[sLB]; 
      couldReverseQ = False,
                  (* 
      prefer straight continuation *)

      nextPoint = If[Length[sLB] <= 3, nearest1[[1]],
                                                 \[ScriptD] = 
         1. Normalize[(sLB[[-1]] - sLB[[-2]]) + 
            1/2 (sLB[[-2]] - sLB[[-3]])];
                                                 \[ScriptN] = {-1, 
           1} Reverse[\[ScriptD]];
                                                \[ScriptS] = 
         Sort[{Sqrt[(\[ScriptD].(# - sLB[[-1]]))^2 + 
                                                                  \
    (* perpendicular *) 2 (\[ScriptN].(# - sLB[[-1]]))^2], # } & /@ 
           nearest1]; 
                                                \[ScriptS][[1, 2]]];
                   AppendTo[sLB, nextPoint];
                  seenQ[nextPoint] = True;
                 counter++ ]];
    AppendTo[lineBag, sLB]];
   (* return segments sorted by length *)

   Reverse[SortBy[Select[lineBag , Length[#] > 12 &], Length]],
   (* monitor progress *)

   Grid[{{Text[Style["progress point joining", Darker[Green, 0.66]]], 
      ProgressIndicator[counter/\[Lambda]]},
               {Text[
       Style["number of segments", Darker[Green, 0.66]]],  
      Length[lineBag] + 1}}, 
            Alignment -> Left, Dividers -> Center]]]
```

Comment: Thank @Chris . I will try now

Comment: I _believe_ you should make this CW or buy Michael Trott a six pack