# How to find the parametric equations of the letters to be able to plot them on Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I am a French high school student, I discovered Wolfram Mathematica a year ago and I wanted to know how to draw the letters of the alphabet on Wolfram Mathematica.

I saw that it was necessary to use parametric equations but I don't really know how to use a parametric equation and especially how to find the parametric equations of all the letters.

I saw that there was already a question of this type for the parametric equation of the letter C, but the answers seemed obscure to me.

I also saw that the question of finding the curves of the objects had already been asked several times but my problem is that my mathematical background does not allow me to understand everything.

I thank you in advance for that.

Comment: `I saw that there was already a question of this type for the parametric equation of the letter C` -- edit your question to provide a link to the referenced question so that others can readily find it.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, here are the different links :  [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/174766/how-to-find-the-parametric-equation-of-the-von-mises-yield-function), [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91514/how-to-draw-the-letter-geometrically-by-points)

Comment: Your second links has a further link to a blog post which shows how to create equations for any shape.

Comment: Indeed, I had not noticed that there was a link further on that allowed me to answer my question.